# listview Popupmenu displays false value

Tags: android, popupmenu, click

Im trying to display the item name of the listview when its popupmenu is being clicked but i'm have trouble with it because it always show or returns "false" value. Any ideas how to solve this? thanks

```
   public void toast(View v){
        showPopupMenu(v);
    }
    private void showPopupMenu(View v){
        PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(CompanyActivity.this, v);
        pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());

        pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.view){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),item.getItemId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                          .show();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        pop.show();
    }
```

Edited: I want to get the value of the list item in the listview being clicked but it shows the menu item that is being clicked.

```
public void toast(View v){
        showPopupMenu(v);
    }
    private void showPopupMenu(View v){
        PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(CompanyActivity.this, v);
        pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());

        pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(CompanyActivity.this,"text: "+item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
                }
            });
        pop.show();
    }
```

Comment: why you do this "item.getItemId() == R.id.view"?

Comment: im checking if the item click is equal to the item in my menu.xml, Am i doing this right?

Comment: if your creating a context menu, you may be doing something wrong, but try take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Comment: im creating a popupmenu which displays the data on that list when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The "name" of your ListView items depends entirely on the adapter you're using for the ListView. Keep in mind that the menu item id is unrelated to the listview view id, which is unrelated to the adapter item id. In order for the popup menu to know which item was clicked, you'll need to use the list item position to look it up from the adapter. It'll work something like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    showPopupMenu(view, position);
}
private void showPopupMenu(View anchor, final int position) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(
            this,
            anchor);
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu);

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // Depending on what type of object backs your adapter, you may have
            // to do something different here.
            String title = String.valueOf(mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position));
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "text: " + title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```